# Nested join query, only last row of third table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

So i've been struggling for hours with this query and i really don't know how to get the result i need. Maybe some of you have a clue ?

Here's my query so far :

```
items = Item.joins(projects: :connexions)
            .where.not(connexions: []).where("connexions.updated_at > ?", 3.years.ago)
```

It's working fine. But what i need are Items, where only **last** connexion "updated_at" on project are greater than 3 years ago.

Basically, i would like to do a items.projects.connexions.last.where etc..

Do you have some tips ?

Thanks :)

**EDIT** : To be more specific about my "connections" specification, i need to retrieve records with projects with no connections since 3 years. That's why i'm using the updated_at field !

**EDIT 2** : I managed to make it work with jvillian answer.

```
items = Item.joins(:projects).where(projects: {id: Project.joins(:connexions).where(
                                              connexions: { id: Connexion.order(updated_at: :desc).limit(1).where("updated_at < ?", 3.years.ago)}
                                             )}
                                            )
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This **may** work for you (untested)

```
Item.where.not(id: 
  Item.joins(:projects).where(
    projects: {id: Project.joins(:connections).where(
      connections: {id: Connection.where("updated_at <= ?", 3.years.ago)}
    )}
  )
)
```

It's pretty ham fisted (if it even works).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not working for what i want :( I need to only retrieve projects where there's absolutely no connections updated_at for the past 3 years. But i'll add that in my question to make it clearer !

Comment: Sorry, missed the **last** connection bit. I'll try to come back later if no one has answered correctly.

Comment: Actually, i work from what you gave me and i finally get it to work thanks to you with this line : connexions: { id: Connexion.order(updated_at: :desc).limit(1).where("updated_at < ?", 3.years.ago) But i agree, it's... not that pretty :p